# Results on forcing extensions for models of CZF

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing, constructive-mathematics, alternative-set-theories

I regard the research on models of ZFC, forcing extensions and related subjects as pretty promising with respect to coping with the incompleteness of ZFC. However, for certain applications I find constructive theories like CZF more applicable.

So, my question is on comparable results on models of CZF or maybe other constructive set theories. Maybe someone knows of some papers where models of constructive theories were researched with a glimpse on cross-model implications. Or papers where existing results on models for ZFC were researched with respect to their applicability on a constructive theory.

I guess there will be some differences, for starters because models of ZFC are supposed to define everything as either true or false, while non-constructive theories are not supposed to have a law of excluded middle.

My apologies for not being able to put this into a more definitive question, but I'm really having problems finding something where to start here, despite having already researched for applicable papers.

Comment: There's J.L. Bell's [book](http://publish.uwo.ca/~jbell/INTBOOK(Repaired).pdf) which contains a chapter on frame-valued models (which is essentially what forcing is doing anyway). Bell does it in IZF, though, so I'm not sure what obstacles CZF might pose to the construction. Probably worth a look, though.

Comment: If my memory serves me right, CZF doesn't really have Replacement axioms, or at least not that many of them, and in that case forcing might fail miserably. Just to paint a picture, forcing with the trivial forcing over a class-model of Zermelo whose von Neumann ordinals are bounded in the full universe may result in adding the rest of the class of ordinals. So without Replacement axioms it also matters a lot how you actually write down the formal definitions.

Comment: @Asaf CZF has the axiom of Replacement; More accurately, they have Strong collection as an axiom and it implies Full Replacement. However, CZF does not have Full separation and we cannot prove Full separation from Strong collection.

Comment: @Hanul: Ah, thanks! I remembered there was something wonky with the schemata, but not the details.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: This is very interesting for me since I have first to figure out which one of the set theories with restricted omniscience principles is most suitable for me. IZF is definitely interesting, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be interested in Gambino's article on forcing over CZF:

> Nicola Gambino. *Heyting-valued interpretations for Constructive Set Theory*. Annals of Pure and Applied Logic **137**, 2006, 164-188.

In this article, Gambino developed the theory of forcing over $\mathsf{CZF}^-$, namely, Constructive ZF without [Subset collection](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subset+collection). (Subset collection is a predicative substitute for the axiom of Power set, in a nutshell.) As an application of his model, Gambino showed that $\mathsf{CZF}^-$ and $\mathsf{CZF}^-$ with the excluded middle for bounded formulas ($\mathsf{\Delta_0}\text{-}\mathsf{LEM}$) are equiconsistent.

Rathjen and Swan made a futher application of Gambino's Heyting-valued models in

> Michael Rathjen and Andrew Swan, *Lifschitz Realizability as a Topological Construction*. arXiv preprint. [arXiv:1806.10047](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.10047).

They showed in this article that $\mathsf{LLPO}_n$ is consistent with some non-classical axioms like $\mathsf{CT}_!$. ($\mathsf{CT}_!$ is the assertion that every *functional* relation over $\omega$ has a computable choice function. For the definition of $\mathsf{LLPO}_n$, see Chapter 8 of Diener's [*Constructive Reverse Mathematics*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.05495.pdf).) Furthermore, they also showed that $\mathsf{CZF+MP+LLPO}_n$ has some existence property.

If we do not restrict our attention to $\mathsf{CZF}$, then articles by Lubarsky (e.g. [this article](http://math.fau.edu/lubarsky/on%20separating%20fan%20theorems%20II.pdf)) provide  examples of applications of forcing over $\mathsf{IZF}$.